# can not redirect to 403 page in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

Hi guys I am trying to restrict customers on frontend on basis on geo location.Issue is when am trying to dispatch 403 status code from observer using `$observer->getControllerAction();` ,It returns null.
Please have a look over the code i have used.
Any help is highly is highly appreciated.

> 

```
  protected function denyAccess($observer)
    {
       $action = $observer->getControllerAction();
       $response = $action->getResponse();
       $response->clearBody()->setStatusCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http::STATUS_CODE_403);
    $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for above problem as getControllerAction method returns NULL due to which further process was not working.I had to used code below and every thing worked fine.

> ```
>     protected function denyAccess($observer)
> {
>     $response = $observer->getResponse();
>     $response->clearBody()->setStatusCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http::STATUS_CODE_403);
>     $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
> }
> ```